# how do i make Acrobat my default?

Tags: adobe-acrobat, file-association

How can I make Acrobat my default to open attachments that come via email and in opening documents? This was previously the case on my computer, but no longer.

Comment: Maybe usefull information would be what email client you are using to achieve this (or webservice, ie. hotmail). And what kind of attachements are you talking about, only pdf or also other extension types? And what do you mean 'in opening documents', documents that did not come through email?

Comment: @Yohsoog The email client should be defaulting to the OS defined program for opening the type of file

Comment: @Aaron I was not sure about that, I thought some clients (ie. thunderbird) supported their own settings that can overrule the default program. Probably your answer is right, it's just that a more descriptive question would be recommended I think.

Answer (score 1):

Right click a PDF and choose Open With -> Choose Program...

Locate Adobe Acrobat in the Programs section and select it. Then select...

> Always use the selected program to
>   open this kind of file

...and then click OK.